# How should I configure nGinx to serve a simple PHP app (routing problems)?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm trying to configure my nGinx server (on a Debian Wheezy box) to serve my small PHP app. I have problems with routing.

What do I need:

/ - no PHP allowed, just .html files

/api - everything goes to /api/index.php, including /api/method1, /api/method2, etc.

That's all.

What do I have right now:

```
server {
    listen 3000;

    root /home/my_user/php/my_app;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files /index.html =404;
    }
    location /api {
            try_files /index.php =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

            # With php5-cgi alone:
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What works:

/ gives me /home/my_user/php/my_app/index.html, that's OK.

/api gives me 404, that's not OK (it should go to the /api/index.php file).
    The same goes for /api/foo. (And yeah, the file /api/index.php exists, and is readable for everyone, just as the api/ subdirectory.)

/api/index.php gives me 404 (but a different one, I'm not sure, what's going on).

According to nginx/php tutorials I have found, everything should be OK. It isn't.

How should I configure my nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config could be simplified.

```
server {
    listen 3000;

    root /home/my_user/php/my_app;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/ {
        try_files /api/index.php =404;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

First, just serve static file is default nginx behavior, there is no need to have some special block for it. `index` directive is enough to make nginx search for `index.html`.

To map any request to `/api/something` to `/api/index.php` you should use full path as `try_files` construct path to file from `root` directive. Also fastcgi directives should be in this location because if `try_files` finds file it's processed in current context, i.e. inside `location /api/`.

There is no need for `location ~ .*\.php$`, because of *“no PHP allowed”*.